# keep cache in sync with FastAPI deployed on K8

Tags: kubernetes, caching, fastapi

We have a [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) [application](https://gitlab.com/eaternity/eos) that we deploy on AWS using Kubernetes. It uses PostgreSQL for storage. In this application, we need to keep some values in memory, else some calculations take too much time. E.g. we keep an in-memory cache of 400k mappings between a string and some glossary object.

In our deployment, there might be multiple instances of our FastAPI application.

What are best practices to keep our caches in sync?

Comment: just curious any chance for redis ? or looking for pods in memory only?

Comment: You definitely want to use some kind of external cache, like redis, memcached, or even storing the calculation results in a separate table in postgres.

Comment: @Chris the multi might work within the same FastAPI server, but not across separate pods, i think

Comment: @M.O. having an external cache will not work for our usecase (too slow). the cache needs to be local, i think. We are holding 400k values in this cache. Having to ask Redis will be too slow.

Comment: @HarshManvar in-memory only for our usecase...

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of any way to keep the python in memory cache in sync between different pods. You could try caching at the kubernetes ingress level, then any requests matching the cache wouldn't even hit your python servers.